# VPN or port forward with SSH for securely managing my home devices

Tags: networking, vpn

I need, for the purpose of managing some IoT devices, external access to my home network. In principle, I am mostly concerned with accessing only one device from the outside.

So far, I've been doing this using SSH, by having a port forward in the router. The SSH was secured by allowing only public key connections (passphrase is disabled), only one user access, and a strong root password.

I've recently started to think about the security of this method (especially after seeing a log full of login attempts from the outside).

Would a VPN be more secure? If so, what would be the best way to implement it? For example, my router, provided by my ISP, has builtin VPN functionality. Are there any security or privacy issues related to using such a system? Should I look into deploying my own VPN?

Comment: Port Forwarding is not really secure, so I use VPN to access my home network.

Comment: @John Why should port forwarding not be "secure"? In this case if the router's VPN-server is less secure then the SHH-server, port forwarding is the way to go!

Comment: Port forwarding is just opening a specific port on your machine, which possibly could be found by others.  VPN is encrypted and inherently more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Both SHH and VPN traffic is encrypted so the security concerning the exchanged data depends on the strength of encryption you are using. With "breaking into the system" VPN has essentially similar security issues like SSH. The standard ports of a VPN-Server will be attacks as much as the standard ports of a SSH server so the security issue is how good is the server you are using protected against attacks.

If you did the configuration correctly and stay on top of security issues it doesn't make much difference which one you use. But using VPN instead of SSH will give you a different set of features (e.g. accessing each device with only one VPN connection instead of several SSH connections for each device), that would be the main point for the decision to switch or not. In terms of security I would advice to implement measures like using a non-standard port etc.